# Why is my if age syntax not working? (Beginner Python)

Tags: python

Well, it's my first day using python 3 and I have come across a problem. My script is supposed to say you're old enough to play if the age entered is over 13, but it says you're old enough even if the age is below 13. The console is also supposed to close when the age is lower than 13.

Here is my script:

```
print("How old are you?")

age = int(input())

if age >= "13":
    print("You are old enough to play! Let's get started!")
else:
    print("You are not old enough.")
    sys.exit("Oh dear")
```

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You are comparing a string to an integer:

```
age = int(input())

if age >= "13":
```

In Python 2, a string is *always* larger than a number. Use numbers instead:

```
if age >= 13:
```

In Python 3, comparing strings with integers like that raises an error instead:

```
>>> 13 >= "13"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() >= str()
```

giving you a clearer message about what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Actually, in Python 2, a string is always *larger* than a number.

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it out. But how do I make the console close when it has said I am too young?

Comment: @kindall: yeah, got my quick test mucked up.

Comment: @Jonathan: You are doing it right already; your program exits.

Comment: It does not work, instead I get this error message:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "(Destination)", line 31, in <module>
        sys.exit("Oh dear")
    NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: @Jonathan: you need to import `sys` first: `import sys`.

Comment: Is still does not close, it just stops me from continuing. Is there anyway for the console to close if the age is less than 13?

Comment: @Jonathan: what console is this? Windows, a linux terminal? How did your program start?

Comment: @Martijin: It's on windows, using the IDLE and then then python shell (I called it the console) opens. Is there any way for it to close?

Comment: No, the IDLE window doesn't close when you call `sys.exit()`; run your script from the Windows console or double-click on the Python file instead.

Comment: How do I run it in the windows console?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare an integer with quotes, the compiler recognizes it as a string and not an int.

```
if age >= 13:
```