# Condition Codes In Python Programing

Tags: python

I typed in Microsoft Visual Studio that

```
answer = input("What Is Your Age ? ")   
if answer >= "18" :  
        print("You Have The Right To Cast Vote In India.")  
else :
        print("You Have No Right To Cast Vote In India.")
```

When user is typing the number greater than equal to 18 then it is showing,"You Have The Right To Cast Vote In India." and when user is typing the number greater than 9 and less then 18 then it is showing,"You Have No Right To Cast Vote In India." Upto this it is working correctly but when user is typing the number less than 10 it is showing,"You Have The Right To Cast Vote In India."
           But I want that it should show,"You Have No Right To Cast Vote In India." when the user type less than 10 and less than 18.
Please Give Me The Solution.

Comment: compare on ints instead of strings.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted. This is a common beginner mistake presented in a well-written, clear question.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81, I agree. I upvoted, because the question is clear, well-written and also useful for other beginners who may make the same mistake.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 Because this is not a place to learn to code from the beginning. This problem shows that the OP doesn't understand even the very basics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my if age syntax not working? (Beginner Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457378/why-is-my-if-age-syntax-not-working-beginner-python)

Comment: @OrangeFlash81: in fact it's an [incredibly common mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+compare+string+integer+is%3Aa), so even *more* a reason for downvoting (for lack of research, not for presentation).

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, not integers.
When comparing strings the comparison is lexicographic:

```
print('101' > '18')
>> False
```

You should convert `answer` to `int` and then compare as integers:

```
answer = int(input("What Is Your Age ? "))
if answer >= 18 :  
        print("You Have The Right To Cast Vote In India.")  
else :
        print("You Have No Right To Cast Vote In India.")
```

This will raise a `ValueError` if the input isn't a valid number which you will have to account for.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare a string `answer` to a string `"18"` as if they were both numbers. This won't work - Python tries to compare them based on alphabetical order instead of numerically.

To achieve what you want, convert `answer` to an integer number using the `int` function, and take `18` out of quotes to make it an integer too:

```
answer = input("What Is Your Age ? ")   
if int(answer) >= 18 :  
        print("You Have The Right To Cast Vote In India.")  
else :
        print("You Have No Right To Cast Vote In India.")
```